# Extracting numbers from String through Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have created a program which gets the string from the putty and kills the processID from getting processID from that string. Currently it is working fine but sometimes it is not reliable.

Please find the target and the regex I used below.

**Target String**: `root     14139     1 25 Aug03 ?        06:47:50 /usr/local`

**RegEx I used**: `\\\d{3,5}`

I want to get the RegEx which can find the immediate number after root and ignore the other text. (e.g., I want to extract 14139 from the example string removing all the extra space.)

How can I do it?

Comment: You used a regex and what was the result? Also, if you want to match "root", you can always add it to the regex pattern, have you tried?

Comment: `s = s.replaceFirst("^.*\\broot\\s+(\\d{3,5}).*$", "$1");`

Comment: try this regex (?:root )[0-9]+

Comment: Hello @WiktorStribiżew - Your code didn't work as expected. I want to extract the string which comes after root, that is 14139.

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh - Your code gives me null value.

Comment: @user3664382 try the code provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need the a number from the second field delimited by spaces. The following regex gets it in the capture group 1:

```
^\S+\s+(\d+)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/bE7xL8/1

And the sample Java code:

```
String input = "root 14139 1 25 Aug03 ? 06:47:50 /usr/local";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\S+\\s+(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/LVLCNm

Comment: Your code works in the demo, but how to utilize them in java code, it gives me the error message.

Comment: It gives me output with root, I want to exclude root and just want the digits.

Comment: The `root` is a part of the whole regex match while you need only the capture group 1 as it is stated in the answer. Please use `Matcher.group()` method to retrieve this capture. The example in https://ideone.com/LVLCNm shows how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this one:

```
^root (\d*)\D?.*
```

capture 1 or more digits after a starting "`root` " string and delimited by not-digit chars

tester:
https://regex101.com/r/sL8oJ7/1

Answer (score 0):

This will be a bit more forgiving and less dependent on number of spaces, again using a capturing group:

`root[^\d]*(\d+)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex and used first group : `root[^\S]*(\d+)`

[Demo and Example](https://regex101.com/r/xO6wP1/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your target string its giving output as required by you.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class exampleproblem {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String target = "root 14139 1 25 Aug03 ?        06:47:50 /usr/local";
    String regexex = "root(.[0-9]+)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(target);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1).trim());
    }
}
}
```